# Issue with my python code

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

```
anwser=str(input("Do you need a new phone? "))

if answer== "no":   
    print ("You are now finished. ")
else:    
    question1=str(input("Do you know what phone you want? ")
    if question1== "no":
        print("Research different phones and chose which pne you like best.")
    else:
        question2=str(input("Do you want to go on a contract? ")
        if question2== "no": 
             question3=str(input("Do you have enought money to pay full price for your phone? ")
```

What is wrong? How do I improve? It keeps coming up with a syntax error and I don not know why.

Comment: There are several missing parenthesis. You need `foo = str(bar)`, not `foo = str(bar`.

Comment: Although the `str` is completely unnecessary anyway.

Comment: What does the syntax error tell you? Also, you should specify what version of Python, since syntax is slightly different between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing closing parentheses on your question lines:

```
question1 = str(input("Do you know what phone you want? ")
```

Should be:

```
question1 = str(input("Do you know what phone you want? "))
```

You also don't need to convert the input to a string, because [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) already does that for you:

> ```
> input([prompt])
> ```
>
> If the *prompt* argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that.